# Spring-data-cassandra framework support for Cassandra java driver 3.0 and server 3.x

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring-data-cassandra framework to perform cassandra related operations. Now that I have to move the C* server to 3.4. This is forcing me to use cassandra java driver 3.0. However what is noticed is the spring-data-cassandra latest version 1.4.Release does not support C* java driver 3.0 yet.

Can anyone on this group update with the details on when the support would be available for java driver 3.x.

Also here is the link to JIRA issue.

Thanks

Comment: We're planning to switch to the 3.x driver with the Ingalls release train. Cannot give you an ETA yet, but it should be available around August, that's the link to our ticket: [DATACASS-271](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-271)

Comment: Thank you very much. I look forward for the upgrade